# If post_type is This or This

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm basically using this bit of code in my `functions.php` to order my custom post types by title in ascending order.

```
function set_custom_post_types_admin_order($wp_query) {
  if (is_admin()) {

    $post_type = $wp_query->query['post_type'];

    if ( $post_type == 'games') {
      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'title');
      $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
    if ( $post_type == 'consoles') {
      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'title');
      $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_custom_post_types_admin_order');
```

Is there a way to combine those two`if` statements, so I'm not repeating code. Something like this:

```
if ( $post_type == 'games' OR 'consoles') OR {
      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'title');
      $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a switch statement and combine your matching cases.

```
function set_custom_post_types_admin_order( $query ) {

    // If not admin or main query, bail.
    if( !is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() ) 
        return;

    $post_type = $query->query['post_type'];

    switch( $post_type ) {
        case 'games':
        case 'consoles':
        //case 'other_example_match':
            $query->set('orderby', 'title');
            $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_custom_post_types_admin_order' );
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you'll want to be real careful when attaching to the pre_get_posts hook. This fires on every single query that gets run throughout your site. I would strongly advise you add another condition or two to the start of your function to limit the scope of this filter.

Secondly, I would suggest checking `if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'games', 'consoles' ) )` as a better alternative for your condition.

The way you're using the OR statement here is actually incorrect, and you'll need to expand out the condition better, e.g. `if ( $post_type == 'games' || $post_type == 'consoles' )`. If you choose to stick with this way of writing the condition, I would also suggest adopting the habit of writing "yoda conditions", like so: `if ( 'games' == $post_type || 'consoles' == $post_type )`.

In a "yoda condition", the value is followed by the variable, making it much easier to spot a missing `=` symbol and an errant statement. Your life will be much happier this way, trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

Double pipes `||` save the day!

```
if ( $post_type == 'games' || $post_type == 'consoles') {
      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'title');
      $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
}
```

This does exactly what I set out to do!

**Edit:**
`or` also works in place of the double pipe. You learn something new every day!

Comment: I don't think this actually works. You can verify by replacing `'consoles'` with `'some random text string'`. The logical syntax is `if ( A OR B )`. In this case, `A` is `$post_type == 'games'`, and `B` is `'consoles'`. Since `B` is just a statement and not a comparison, it will always return `true`.

Comment: Aside from that, there's the single `OR` after the conditional statement and the opening curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
```

Or other examples you can see it here: http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/when-to-use-pre_get_posts-in-wordpress/

Comment: Sorry, how would I apply this to the above code?

Comment: Please explain why this is helpful and why it works.